# Ajax form submit. form submitted twice

Tags: ajax, cakephp, form-submit, double-submit-problem

I am working with cakePHP and in my view I have a form which has an ajax submit button. I rendered it using the cake helpers.

```
    <form method="post" class="form-class" id="form-id" name="form1" style="display: none">
                *[content for the form]*
                    <?php
                    echo $ajax->submit('Ok',
                            array(
                                       'id'=> 'submit1',
                                        'url'=> array('controller'=>'c','action'=>'action1'),
                                        'complete'=> 'jsfunction()'

                                ));
                    echo $form->button('Submit',array('id'=>'cancel','value'=>'Cancel','onClick'=>'clickCancel()'));
                    ?>


</form>
```

When I click submit, the controller action is called twice. I searched stackOverlow if this question existed but couldn't find a valid solution. There are no syntax errors.

Help will be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked in different browsers???

Comment: Can you show any code from the generated page? (i can only speculate what $ajax->submit() is doing, would be nice to see the JS code it appears to be auto-generating for you on the client's end).

Comment: I know this doesn't help, but I have been having the same problem myself. I really hope that someone will be able to help with this.

Comment: As I said to OP, can you post the generated code some place so we can see what JS is being applied to the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the ajax event handlers aren't blocking the default behaviour.
Try setting the form's onsubmit behaviour inline to prevent it (as cake's helper does):

```
<form onsubmit="event.returnValue = false; return false;" method="post" class="form-class" id="form-id" name="form1" style="display: none">
```

I recommend checking out the [FormHelper](http://api13.cakephp.org/class/form-helper) for some useful shortcuts around this.

Answer (score 1):

This is the auto generated code:

```
 $("#submit1367508668").bind('click', function(){ 
     $.ajax({
              async:true, 
              type:'post', 
              complete:function(request, json) {
                   getServerResponse(request)
              }, 
              url:'/recipients/add', 
              dataType:'json', 
              data:$(this).parents('form:first').serialize()}); 
              blockUI(); 
     })
```

Comment: Well Im actually using the FormHelper along with the Ajax helper to produce the code output and I modified the options to include the event.returnValue = false bit of it as it was the only thing missing, but still no go.