# Built in this->js->submit cakephp runs twice

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp-2.1, helper

Fellow programmers.

I only found [this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824859/ajax-form-submit-form-submitted-twice) to my problem, which did not help.

I am having trubble with cake phps built in **$this->Js->submit**

**What I want to do:**

Site on which my logic starts contains a table with my data. On this site I also have several elements that contain forms and are opened by a modal window (jquery ui dialog)

1. Insert an object to database. *(working)*
2. The form by which I insert is in a modal dialog window. *(working)*
3. The submit button is an image. *(working)*
4. Before the form is submitted, validation is fired *(working)*
5. After the form is submitted, close the modal and put new object on the first line of a table *(working)*.

**So what is my problem?**

Everything fires twice.

** CODE **

Since All my other code seems to be working I'm gonna paste only the **$this->Js->submit** part of my code, so you guys can focus on what seems to be the problem.

If any other code is required, please write to me and I will be happy to paste some more in the edit section.

```
echo $this->Js->submit(' ', array (
        'label' => 'Send',
        'onsubmit'=>"event.returnValue = false; return false;",
        'div'   => array('class' => 'send_button'), //style submit to be an image
        'url'   => array('controller' => 'records', 'action' => 'append_new_record'),
        'type' => 'json',
        'success' => '
            if (data.success == true) {
                $("#element_add").dialog("close");
                var newLine = data.recordLine;
                $("#content").find("table tbody").find("tr:first").before(newLine);
            }
            else { 
                $("#element_add").html(data.form);
            }
            ',
        'buffer' => false, //true did not help (refreshes the whole web site)
        'before' => '
            if (!checkAdd()) { //validation (custom js function)
                return false;
            }
        '
    ));
```

**What I tried**

1. Adding a return false line at the end of 'success' block of code.
2. Adding an event.preventDefault() at the start of 'before' block of code.

**EDIT1 HERE IS THE GENERATED HTML CODE**

```
    </script><div class="send_button"><input  id="submit-1182269389" type="submit" value=" "/></div><script type="text/javascript">

$("#submit-1182269389").bind("click", function (event) {$.ajax({beforeSend:function (XMLHttpRequest) {
                if (!checkAdd()) {
                    return false;
                }
            }, data:$("#submit-1182269389").closest("form").serialize(), dataType:"json", label:"Send", onsubmit:"event.returnValue = false; return false;", success:function (data, textStatus) {
                if (data.success == true) {
                    $("#element_add").dialog("close");
                    var newLine = data.recordLine;
                    $("#okno").find("table tbody").find("tr:first").before(newLine);
                }
                else {
                    $("#element_add").html(data.form);
                }
                }, type:"post", url:"\/my_app\/records\/append_new_record"});
return false;});

</script></form>
```

**EDIT2 1. TRY THAT DID NOT WORK**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#addForm').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

So this blocks the whole ajax thing (the data are appended to the table after refreshing the page and still twice)

Comment: It might be useful to add the actual HTML source that is output to the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by a great workaround, so if anybody provides information why this is behaving this way I will be glad.

My solution:

- Added a hidden input

  ```
  $this->Form->input('submit_type', array('id'=>'add_submit_type', 'type'=>'hidden', 'value'=>0));
  ```
- In before I added this block of code

  ```
  var value = $("#add_submit_type").val();
  if (value == 1) {
      $("#add_submit_type").val("0");
  } else {
      $("#add_submit_type").val("1");
  }
  ```
- In my PHP, I don't allow the object creation if $this->request->data's submit_type == 0.